# Fabric doesn't report fatal crashes on android

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I use `fabric` with `crashlytics` plugin
I have following code in the onCreate:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

I receive daily reports from fabric.What's strange is in the reports crash-free users is less than 100% but I don't see opened issues in the fabric dashboard.Moreover some crashes fabric does report with emails like:

> A fatal issue was closed, but it popped up again in version 1.0.1

Does it normal behaviour?If not how can I receive reports for all crashes?

Comment: It seems like one of the issues (Fatal Crash) that you thought is fixed and closed it earlier has re-appeared. Maybe it was not fixed properly. Or maybe there are few users still on old version which has that issue. That's why you don't see "open" issues but you are still getting crashes.

Comment: but why then for some crashes fabric reopens issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't notify on each crash as that would be overwhelming for many developers. We will notify you when an issue is new, regressed or in the stability digest. If you close an issue and then we detect that the crash happened in a different version where we haven't seen the crash before, then we will re-open it and mark it is a regression which is the notification you received.

On your Fabric dashboard, we default to open issues in the past 7 days with your app's top builds based on daily active users. If you don't see the issue in your dashboard, I'd recommend adjusting the filters to select all issues and all versions.

Comment: Thanks.I guess these crashes was for earlier builds.

BTW: is there way to get statistics on all crashes depending on build version?

Comment: You can select any version in the Crashlytics dashboard and see the crash-free users and sessions for that version. Just select All issues and you'll see the full data.